# mongoDB use timestamp from _id to evaluate whether its been accessed within last 24 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, timestamp

first time posting something, until now lurking always brought some answers. I hope i can also give back this way, but just started out programming a few months ago.

so here we go: I run a website without a Database backend yet and want to add some functionality. The website is currently running on a vps with nodejs and nginx. The database JSON files should look like that:

```
{account:"1241423",
 counter:0,
 _id:"someid"}
```

evertime someone passes me an account number through the webform i want to check if its inside the DB, no problem with that. When i find it i also want to check when its last been accessed (using the timestamp of the _id), if it was more or less than 24 hours ago. if its been more than 24 hours ago i want to increment the counter by 1 and also want to give it a new _id so the time of access gets updated as well. I went through some of the documentation and a few articles and yt videos but didnt quite find what i was looking for.

so lets say i save the JSON file to a temporary js object called "accountInfo":

- how do i check whether the creation/update date is more or less than 24 hours in the past by using the accountInfo._id property?

edit: iam currently using mongodb with nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId carries only one timestamp and, normally, it is of its creation (obviously). If you want to check when an item was last updated (or accessed), you have to have separate fields for this, and also write code in your app that keeps these timestamps accurate (touches `updated_at` when you update a document, etc.)

You can extract the timestamp portion by using [`getTimestamp()` method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#getTimestamp)

```
my_accountinfo._id.getTimestamp()
```

Comment: well, if i would update the _id everytime i access it, it would always stay up to date. in my case the account numbers would already be my identifier.

Comment: @code4meplz: the problem is, you can't update _id. you'll have to create a new record, with a new id, and destroy the old one.

Comment: alright, that i didnt know, thank you. thought i might be able to save a field :P